# Problemas con PRIMARY key

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Primero que todo, para entender mi problemática debemos tener claro las siguientes circunstancias:

Tenemos la tabla s1_subscripciones con la siguiente estructura

```
ID --- PRIMARY KEY

uid

Mail

Fecha
```

Ahora supongamos que está vacía la tabla.
Cuando yo lanzo el comando

```
INSERT INTO s1_subscripciones (uid, mail, fecha) VALUES ('5', 'tommy000@nauta.cu', '25-05-2021');
```

La fila quedaría así

```
ID --- 1

Uid ---5

Mail --- tommy000@nauta.cu

Fecha --- 25-05-2021
```

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero...

Cuando yo vuelvo a lanzar ese comando con otros datos diferentes la columna ID en vez de aumentar 1 aumenta 5 o 6 valores quedaría así

```
ID --- 6

Uid ---51

Mail --- pepito@nauta.cu

Fecha --- 25-05-2021
```

En resumen

Mi problemática es q cuando añades una fila a una tabla en valor autoincrement en vez de aumentar 1 aumenta 5 o 6 valores, este problema lo estoy teniendo desde hace rato y me es un problema muy grave para mí script

Este es el proceso de creacion de la tabla

```
CREATE TABLE s1_subscripcion ( 
    id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    uid int(255) DEFAULT 0, 
    mail varchar(255) DEFAULT '0', 
    fecha_subs int(255) DEFAULT current_timestamp(), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es el id?,  además ¿qué algoritmo desarrollaste pára incrementar el valor?

Comment: Seria bueno que también subas el código de la creación de tu tabla, eso nos ayudara a entender si el problema esta en como incrementa el valor de _id_

Comment: Si el valor que aumenta no es fijo (dices que a veces aumenta `5`, a veces `6`) queda descartado que tengas definido un ritmo diferente de aumento de 1 en 1 (puedes definir en la tabla que los autoincrement cambien de `N` en `N`). Lo que podría estar ocurriendo es que hay intentos de inserción fallidos en cualquier parte de tu código. El autoincrement aumenta cuando un intento de inserción falla, lo que podría provocar saltos en la secuencia. Sea como sea, comparte el resultado de `SHOW CREATE TABLE s1_subscripciones` para verificar el estado exacto de tu tabla.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `s1_subscripcion` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `uid` int(255) DEFAULT 0,
 `mail` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
 `fecha_subs` int(255) DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=202 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8         ESTO ES LO Q ME LANZA CUANDO PONGO EL SHOW CREATE TABLE, hay q tener en cuenta que está tabla ya tiene registros

Comment: @Tommy-traviline, Presiona el botón [edit] y agrega esa info en la pregunta. PD: El nombre de la tabla y los campos no se corresponden.